# How to add "vcl.bpi" to BPL project

Tags: bpl, c++builder-2009

I use C++ builder 2009 to create a BPL project. The "**Requires**" list has "***rtl.bpi***" as default. I add some VCL Forms to the "**Contains**" list and try to build the BPL project. The build fails due to linker error such as "*Unresolved external 'Forms::TForm::' referenced from XXX.OBJ*". It is obvious that I should add "***vcl.bpi***" to the "**Requires**" list. I do the following steps:

1. Right-click on "**Requires**" and select "**Add Reference**".
2. In the "**Add**" dialog-->"**Requires**" tab, key "vcl.bpi" in the "**Package name**" text edit, and the click "OK".
3. It pops an error dialog shows "*File vcl.bpi not found*".

How should I add "vcl.bpi" manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put in only the filename by itself, you need to fill in the "Search Path" field of the dialog with the folder that the file resides in.

Otherwise, specify the full path to the file.

Either way, you can use the **Browse** button to simplify this.

The file is located in the `$(BCB)\lib\win32\release` folder.

Comment: Hi @Remy, thanks a lot. It works. However, isn't **$(BCB)\lib\release(or\debug)** in the default search path? Why **_vcl.bpi_** can not be found as **_rtl.bpi_**? After all, manually add search path works. I have another question that why BPL project's **Options|Packages|Build with runtime packages** checkbox is disabled? Sometimes it is checked and sometimes not, and I can not modify it.